# What is the "Android Class Name" for a Facebook app written in Flex?

Tags: android, facebook, apache-flex

When setting up a Facebook app, it requires an Android Package Name and Android Class Name.

The first part is easy, and Google Play even shows me this in my list of apps.

How do I find the Android Class Name for a Flex app?

[image: Facebook App Settings]

Comment: I'm not understanding.  **What** requires an Android Package Name and Android class name?  How are you setting up a Facebook app?

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the Facebook settings that ask for this.

Comment: I'm guessing this relates to the id field of your app manifest file; but that is just a guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this [link](http://www.jamesward.com/2011/05/11/extending-air-for-android/),

> The class is named AppEntry and its package name depends on the AIR application ID, but it always begins with “air”.

Answer (score 4):

As you rightly guessed, the package name is straightforward and can be obtained by looking at the google play url, or inside the list of apps section on google play.
But in reality, Google Play itself picks up the name from the AndroidManifest.xml file.
You can find out both the package name and the class name from the AndroidManifest.xml file.
 Regardless of what tool you use for building the app, it must finally be an APK file and the manifest xml file will be inside the apk.
If you view the manifest xml file, the Android Package Name is the value under the "package=" attribute element.
 Eg - if that line read - package="com.example.APP1", then your Android Package name is - com.example.APP1. 
For the Android Class Name, you should look at the manifest file and identify which activity it is, that references the MAIN and LAUNCHER action. 
It will usually start with a "." 
For eg, if it says ".MainClass", then your Android Class Name becomes - com.example.APP1.MainClass (using com.example.APP1 as the application package name from above.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, this is good.  I got to the AndroidManifest.xml file but it's not a readable XML file - it's a binary file.  Because I'm awesome, I managed to decode it enough to find my package name and see that it was immediately followed by "application activity .AppEntry".  So I guess that's the answer, but I don't like it much for a solution.  Can anyone confirm that .AppEntry is always the class name of the main activity for a Flex application, or will it involve this rigmarole every time?

Answer (score 1):

"Android Class Name" refers to class name of your application's Launcher Activity defined in AndroidManifest.xml.
that should be defined with below intent filter in your Android Manifest.xml

```
<intent-filter >
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```